# Canvas dont show animation

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib-animation

I need to show live data from serial port into a canvas of PyQt5.

Using PyQt5 and imported Ui file(MainTest_1.ui), Here I should get live data from serial port and after putting a number in the **Port line edit** and pushing the **Plot button** in my GUI, animation should be seen.
Matplot as a custom class is made in the mpl.py
file:

```
`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Mpl(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mpl, self).__init__(parent)#QWidget.__init__(self, parent)super(MplWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)`
```

main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread # A thread is a separate flow of execution
import serial
import time
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import struct
import pandas as pd


class serialPlot:
    def __init__(self, serialPort = 'COM3', serialBaud = 38400, plotLength = 100, dataNumBytes = 2):
        self.port = serialPort
        self.baud = serialBaud
        self.plotMaxLength = plotLength
        self.dataNumBytes = dataNumBytes
        self.rawData = bytearray(dataNumBytes) # returns a bytearray object which is an array of given bytes
        self.data = collections.deque([0] * plotLength, maxlen=plotLength) # The [0] * x creates a list with x elements.
                                                                           # So,maximum items in deque
        self.isRun = True
        self.isReceiving = False
        self.thread = None
        self.plotTimer = 0
        self.previousTimer = 0
        self.csvData = []

        print('Trying to connect to: ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        try:
            self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(serialPort, serialBaud, timeout=4)
            print('Connected to ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        except:
            print("Failed to connect with " + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')

    def readSerialStart(self):
        if self.thread == None:
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.backgroundThread)
            # read from the serial connection and assign the data to the self.rawData variable. In this manner,
            # whenever the plotting function reads this variable, it will always have the latest data
            # irregardless of the plotting rate (speed at which you plot the data).
            self.thread.start()
            # Block till we start receiving values
            # Thread finished after the Main section of the code did
            while self.isReceiving != True:
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def backgroundThread(self):    # retrieve data
        time.sleep(1.0)  # give some buffer time for retrieving data
        self.serialConnection.reset_input_buffer() # it is necessary to clean the buffer because, the last reading
        ## flush possibly available input
        while (self.isRun):
            self.serialConnection.readinto(self.rawData) # loading the content of self.serialConnection to data rawData
            self.isReceiving = True
            #print(self.rawData)
            valuee, = struct.unpack('f', self.rawData)  # use 'h' for a 2 byte integer
            self.data.append(valuee)

            print(valuee)
    def getSerialData(self,  frame, lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText):
        currentTimer = time.perf_counter() # calculate the time interval-measure the time spent during sleep
        self.plotTimer = int((currentTimer - self.previousTimer) * 1000)     # the first reading will be erroneous
        self.previousTimer = currentTimer
        timeText.set_text('Plot Interval = ' + str(self.plotTimer) + 'ms')
        value,  = struct.unpack('f', self.rawData)    # use 'h' for a 2 byte integer
        self.data.append(value)    # we get the latest data point and append it to our array
        # separate the data acquisition and plotting
        lines.set_data(range(self.plotMaxLength), self.data)
        lineValueText.set_text('[' + lineLabel + '] = ' + str(value))
        self.csvData.append(self.data[-1])



    def close(self):
        self.isRun = False
        self.thread.join() # stop the execution of the current program until a thread is complete

        self.serialConnection.close()
        print('Disconnected...')

class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__()

        #loadUi("RealTime_testU.ui", self)
        loadUi("MainTest_1.ui", self)

        self.setWindowTitle("First PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")
        #self.lineEditPort.returnPressed.connect(self.getDataText)
        #self.lineEditPort.mousePressEvent = self.getDataText # It works well
        #self.lineEditPort.returnPressed.connect(self.getDataText)
        self.lineEditPort.textChanged.connect((lambda: self.check(self.lineEditPort)))
        """ Here for passing argument to a function we should just use lammbda."""
        self.Plot.clicked.connect(self.getDataText)
        self.Plot.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)
        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.Mpl.canvas, self))

    def check(self, wid):
        """Here make sure if the called entary is number or not """
        number = wid.text()
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.about(self, 'Error', 'Input can only be a number')
            #self.input.clear()
            pass



    def getDataText(self):
        """process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC000040) if mouseEvent is passed as argument"""
        self.ffs = float(self.lineEditPort.text())
        print(self.ffs)
        return

    def plot_graph(self):
        portName = 'COM3'
        baudRate = 38400  # one event per second-able to transfer at 38400/(4*8) = 1200Hz
        # it will be meaningless to plot all the 1000 points in a second because your screen can probably only refresh at a
        # rate of 60Hz, so even if the program can do it, you will not be able to visualize it.
        maxPlotLength = 100
        dataNumBytes = 4  # number of bytes of 1 data point
        s = serialPlot(portName, baudRate, maxPlotLength, dataNumBytes)  # initializes all required variables
        s.readSerialStart()  # starts background thread

        # plotting starts below
        pltInterval = 50  # Period at which the plot animation updates [ms]#0.02 second
        xmin = 0
        xmax = maxPlotLength
        ymin = -(1)
        ymax = 1
        # normalize the data between -1 and 1 /dataset - How to normalize data between -1 and 1 - Cross Validated/
        self.Mpl.canvas.axes = plt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax),
                      ylim=(float(ymin - (ymax - ymin) / 10), float(ymax + (ymax - ymin) / 10)))  # ???
        self.Mpl.canvas.axes.set_title('Arduino Analog Read')
        self.Mpl.canvas.axes.set_xlabel("time")
        self.Mpl.canvas.axes.set_ylabel("AnalogRead Value")
        self.Mpl.canvas.axes.grid(True)
        lineLabel = 'Potentiometer Value'
        timeText = self.Mpl.canvas.axes.text(0.50, 0.95, '', transform=self.Mpl.canvas.axes.transAxes)
        lines = self.Mpl.canvas.axes.plot([], [], label=lineLabel)[0]
        lineValueText = self.Mpl.canvas.axes.text(0.50, 0.90, '', transform=self.Mpl.canvas.axes.transAxes)
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.Mpl.canvas.figure, s.getSerialData, fargs=( lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText),
                                       interval=pltInterval, frames=100)  # fargs has to be a tuple

        self.Mpl.canvas.draw()
        s.close()




app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

And the MainTest_1.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>688</width>
    <height>556</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777211</width>
    <height>16777211</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="baseSize">
   <size>
    <width>20</width>
    <height>10</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
      <item>
       <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Plot">
         <property name="baseSize">
          <size>
           <width>60</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Plot</string>
         </property>
         <property name="autoRepeatDelay">
          <number>30</number>
         </property>
         <property name="autoRepeatInterval">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Pause">
         <property name="baseSize">
          <size>
           <width>60</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Pause</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_8">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>8</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_7">
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLabel" name="BaudRate">
              <property name="maximumSize">
               <size>
                <width>16777215</width>
                <height>16777214</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="autoFillBackground">
               <bool>false</bool>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:9pt;&quot;&gt;BaudRate:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
              </property>
              <property name="textFormat">
               <enum>Qt::MarkdownText</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="margin">
               <number>8</number>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBoxBR"/>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6">
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLabel" name="Port">
              <property name="text">
               <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:9pt;&quot;&gt;Port:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
              </property>
              <property name="margin">
               <number>8</number>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEditPort">
              <property name="maximumSize">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="frame">
               <bool>true</bool>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="Ymax">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Ymax</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
             <item>
              <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnAYmax">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Auto</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
               <item>
                <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnMAYmax">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Manual</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_Ymax">
                 <property name="enabled">
                  <bool>true</bool>
                 </property>
                 <property name="maximumSize">
                  <size>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                  </size>
                 </property>
                 <property name="frame">
                  <bool>true</bool>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="Ymin">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Ymin</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
             <item>
              <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnAYmin">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Auto</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
               <item>
                <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnMYmin">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Manual</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_Ymin">
                 <property name="enabled">
                  <bool>true</bool>
                 </property>
                 <property name="maximumSize">
                  <size>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                  </size>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="Xmax">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Xmax</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
             <item>
              <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnAXmax">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Auto</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
               <item>
                <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rarbtnMXmax">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Manual</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_Xmax">
                 <property name="enabled">
                  <bool>true</bool>
                 </property>
                 <property name="maximumSize">
                  <size>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                  </size>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="Xmin">
            <property name="title">
             <string>Xmin</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
             <item>
              <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnAXmin">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Auto</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
               <item>
                <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbtnMXmin">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Manual</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_Xmin">
                 <property name="enabled">
                  <bool>true</bool>
                 </property>
                 <property name="maximumSize">
                  <size>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                  </size>
                 </property>
                 <property name="baseSize">
                  <size>
                   <width>0</width>
                   <height>0</height>
                  </size>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="Mpl" name="Mpl" native="true"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>688</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionOpen_CSV_File"/>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen_CSV_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open CSV File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Mpl</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>mpl.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

This is my code. Constantly without rising any error I got:
0.302734375
-1.0
-0.837890625
0.998046875
Disconnected...
and nothing is being shown on the canvas.